# .htaccess rewrite 301 rules not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am in the process of simplifying my URLs and have come up with a problem concerning the use of Rewrite in htaccess files.

Search engines currently list my pages in the following format

`www.example.com/x/x/article_a/1159/`

which is currently rewritten by the following htaccess file placed in the /x/x directory

```
RewriteRule walk_a/(.*)/$ /x/x/article_a.php?id=$1
```

This has worked fine for many years.

I want to simplify the URL to

`www.example.com/article-1159-introduction`

I have tried the following redirects placed in the root

```
RewriteRule ^x/x/article_a/(.*)/$ http://www.example.com/article-$1-introduction [R=301,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^article-(.*)-introduction$ /x/x/article_a.php?id=$1
```

The 301 rewrite seems to have no effect although the second rewrite command works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `/x/x/.htaccess` directory use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article_a/(.*)/$ /article-$1-introduction [R=301,NC,L,NE]
```

Then inside root .htaccess have this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^article-(.+)-introduction$ /x/x/article_a.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanksfor your reply. I have two htacess files - one in /x/x and one in the root

Comment: Is `article_a.php` located inside `/x/x/`?

Comment: Yes that's what I thought. Did you try my updated answer (requires a rule in both .htaccess)

Comment: Just treid it and it works! Many thanks for your help. I must now try and understand why it works!

Comment: if i have more than one rewrite rule do I need to delete the L tag in brackets?

Comment: No you don't need to remove `L`.